# NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate methods not getting called when downloading files over 50 MB via cellular

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, newsstand-kit

Supposing I have a snippet of code like this:

```
[assetDownload downloadWithDelegate:self];
```

All the three delegate methods are implemented:

```
– connection:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes:
– connectionDidResumeDownloading:totalBytesWritten:expectedTotalBytes:
– connectionDidFinishDownloading:destinationURL:
```

And everything works (the delegate methods get called) fine when there is a WI-FI connection for files of any size, and for files under 50 MB when on cellular network. When the file is bigger and the connection is cellularnone of the methods get called. Is this a normal behavior and what should I do to handle it properly?

Comment: [Apple supposedly allows files of up to 100 Megs through cellular connections](http://www.engadget.com/2013/09/18/apple-raises-cellular-download-cap-to-100mb-for-ios/), but I wonder if your local carrier has their own local download limit?

Comment: I'm able to download files of any size via my carrier.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann that's for apps

Comment: Have you checked the value of allowsCellularAccess on your session configuration? What type of session do you have?

Comment: NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL];
NSLog(@"%hhd",[req allowsCellularAccess]); //returns 1
NKAssetDownload* assetDownload = [nkIssue addAssetWithRequest:req];